Decimation in the 1D Ising model
I'm trying to derive equation 5.6.24 from Chaikin and Lubensky Principles of Condensed Matter
Following the derivation in chapter 5.6:

A new lattice with block spin variables can be obtained in the 1D
Ising model merely by tracing (decimating) over blocks of ( b - 1 )
spins leaving a spin at every ( b )th site, as shown in Fig. 5.6.1.
The partition function of the new lattice is identical to that of the
original lattice and can be expressed as \begin{align} Z_N(K, L, C) &=\mathrm{Tr} M^N = \mathrm{Tr}[M^b]^{N'} = Z_{N'}(K', L', C'),
\tag{5.6.22} \end{align} where ( N' = N/b ) is the number of sites
in the new lattice. The potentials of the decimated lattice are
determined by \begin{align} M(K', L', C') = M^b(K, L, C). \tag{5.6.23}
\end{align}
When ( L = 0 ), this leads, with the help of Eq. (5.6.3), to a
simple relation \begin{align} \tanh K' = (\tanh K)^b, \tag{5.6.24}
\end{align}

Where eq 5.6.3 is defined in

\begin{align} e^{K(\sigma, \sigma')} &= e^C  \begin{bmatrix} e^{K+L} & e^{-K} \\ e^{-K} & e^{K-L} \end{bmatrix} \equiv M(K, L, C),\tag{5.6.2} \end{align}
When ( h = 0 ) and ( C = 0 ), ( M(K, L, C) ) takes on a simple
form, \begin{align} M(K, 0, 0) = \cosh K \left( 1 + \sigma \sigma'
 \tanh K \right). \tag{5.6.3} \end{align}

However It's not clear to me how 5.6.3 leads to 5.6.24, as using the
relation in 5.6.23 we have:
$$\cosh{K'}(1+\sigma\sigma'\tanh{K'})=\cosh{K}^b(1+\sigma\sigma'\tanh{K})^b$$
What am I missing?

Hi. Please do not use images/screenshots for text and equation. Rather, type the relevant passage using MathJax.

The fastest way is probably to compute the logarithm of $M$. Physically, this amounts to replacing the discrete lattice by a continuous version:
$$
Z = \operatorname{Tr}(M^N) = \operatorname{Tr}(e^{NA})
$$
For hermitian $2\times2$ matrices, you can do this easily using Pauli matrices:
$$
\sigma_i\sigma_j = \delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k
$$
A matrix can be always uniquely written as:
$$
A = \alpha+a\cdot\sigma
$$
and:
$$
e^A = e^\alpha\cosh(|a|)+e^\alpha\frac{\sinh(|a|)}{|a|}a\cdot\sigma
$$
Therefore, if you start with:
$$
M = \mu+m\cdot \sigma = e^A
$$
you can easily solve for $\alpha,a$:
$$
\alpha = \frac12\ln(\mu^2-|m|^2) \quad a = \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{|m|}\mu\right)\frac m{|m|}
$$
Your original $M$ has (for $L=0$):
$$
\mu = e^{C+K} \quad m = \begin{pmatrix}e^{C-K}\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
so:
$$
\alpha = C+\frac12\ln(e^{2K}-e^{-2K}) \quad a = \begin{pmatrix}-\frac12\ln\tanh K\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus, when integrating out every $b$ sites, you have:
$$
M\to M^b \quad A\to b A \quad -\frac12\ln\tanh K\to -\frac b2\ln\tanh K
$$
so indeed:
$$
\tanh K \to (\tanh K)^b
$$
This may seem like overkill for your simple problem, but already if you want to treat the slightly more general case $L\neq 0$, it is quite convenient.
